# How convert word document to pdf in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf, blob, docx

I have method on Node js Return Word document , i want pass parameter called file type to convert this word document 
to PDF.

the output from buf var it file like below
`PK
       ! ߤ�l         [Content_Types].xml<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>...`

How can convert this word document to pdf ?

```
router.get("/hello", function(request, response, next,fileType) {

  var zip = new JSZip(
    "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",
    { base64: true }
  );
  var doc = new Docxtemplater();

  doc.loadZip(zip);
  //set the templateVariables
  doc.setData({});

  try {
    // render the document (replace all occurences of {first_name} by John, {last_name} by Doe, ...)
    doc.render();
    var buf = doc.getZip().generate({ type: "nodebuffer" });


    if(fileType=='docx'){
    response.writeHead(200, {
      "Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=" + "template.docx",
      "Content-Type":
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    });
    }else if(fileType=='pdf'){

        //here should convert 
    }

    response.end(buf);
  } catch (error) {
    var e = {
      message: error.message,
      name: error.name,
      stack: error.stack,
      properties: error.properties
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ error: e }));
    // The error thrown here contains additional information when logged with JSON.stringify (it contains a property object).
    throw error;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use a package for this. Although the package I found, require the file to be read from disk it seems and not from buffer.

[`docx-pdf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-pdf): `npm i docx-pdf`

```
const docxConverter = require('docx-pdf');

docxConverter('./input.docx','./output.pdf', (err, result) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(result); // writes to file for us
});
```

Another option is to use an external API like https://github.com/Api2Pdf/api2pdf.node#readme (you could maybe even host it yourself, if you're handling sensitive data).

Comment: A new option is https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativedocuments/docx-wasm and it can read the docx from a buffer

Comment: Based on the [source code](https://github.com/VuongVu/word2pdf/blob/master/index.js), word2pdf uses a web service (convertonlinefree.com) for the conversion. This may not be acceptable for some use cases (i.e. sensitive data). So I just want to point it out.

Comment: Also worth notting that `docx-pdf` is a mare wrapper that uses under the hood `mammoth` to convert docx to html and then `html-pdf`. `mammoth` does not keep the structure of the docx so you'll see somewhat simplified text structure eventually.

Comment: word2pdf was considered a malicious code by npm team and should be removed from your answer

Answer (score 3):

Its pretty simple if you use `libreoffice-convert` library.

Code :

```
const libre = require('libreoffice-convert');

const fs = require('fs');

function convertToPdf(filePath) {

   const file = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
 
   libre.convert(file, extend, undefined, (err, done) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`Error converting file: ${err}`);
      }
 
      fs.writeFileSync('outputFile.pdf', done);
  });
}
```

You can find more documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libreoffice-convert).

Comment: Note: this package has a dependency on the LibreOffice software itself.

Comment: On windows libreoffice-convert and libreoffice-convert-win  won´t work for many

Comment: Also, this is very inefficient that only one file can be converted at one time. No concurrent conversions.