# Creation of custom contracts on the server? Converting DOCX to PDF in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf, docx

this kind of question [has already been asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586207/how-convert-word-document-to-pdf-in-nodejs), but I found no satisfactory answers. They either require libre office to be installed on the system or to use third party API's.

Our usecase is that we generate contracts for each user, the issue is that PDF's are hard to replace placeholder values, so we are doing that with a .docx file but for printing and  integrity of the layout we'd like to have them be PDF's after they've been populated with the correct data.

What would be the best approach here, should we scrap .docx template entirely and try and go with the PDF's from the start? Should we deploy our own API for converting the docs?

Comment: @KJ I must use Nodejs as that is our backend, and the pdftron seems really cool but it's paid and we're outsourcing our contracts to third party which I am not too keen on. Isn't there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, we have an existing server written in Nodejs that uses the data and uses a .docx template and edits it to replace the placeholders. I am not sure how I can use the VBM here? Not familiar with it so not really sure what you're referring to